# Merge [cmake-custom-command] and [add-custom-command] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I've (very) recently created [cmake-custom-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake-custom-command) tag due to a couple of questions of mine; I've added a tag description; and then gone ahead and searched and added this tag to a bunch of relevant questions.

... but then I started noticing questions with [add-custom-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/add-custom-command). I retagged one, then noticed there are actually quite a few. However, there's no tag info or detailed description.

I believe [cmake-custom-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake-custom-command) is a better choice of tag name, because:

1. The mechanism involved another CMake command, `add_custom_target`.
2. With `add-custom-command`, people might use this tag for non-CMake-related questions, since it's a bit vague/generic.

So I suggest the existing tag's questions be mass-retagged, and that [add-custom-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/add-custom-command) be kept as a synonym.